# Does the Redshift JDBC DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion() return an up to date value?

Tags: amazon-redshift

My question is how to get proper redshift Database version information from a Redshift JDBC Connection.
Calling the JDBC DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion() and DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMinorVersion simply returns 8 and 0 which I believe is just some hardcoded values. Is there a JDBC driver API call to get the some reasonable values?

My fallback solution is to use the **VERSION** function as documented in  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VERSION.html and extract the cluster version.
This though requires me to run an SQL where I would like to use pure JDBC API calls.
It also returns a long string (see below) and we would need to parse this string to get the cluster version (E.g 1.0.7804).

The VERSION function returns a string like the following
"*PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.7804*"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS CLI / API to call redshift describe-cluster-db-revisions

e.g. using cli

```
aws redshift describe-cluster-db-revisions
```

This returns a json object describing each cluster including an object "CurrentDatabaseRevision" which contains the current db revision. Currently for me this shows as "7562".

See

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/describe-cluster-db-revisions.html
```

and

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeClusterDbRevisions.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Though this is not an option for me. Need to access through JDBC. That the CurrentDatabaseRevision give the result "7562" was though good to know. The string return when calling the function VERSION contains  "Redshift 1.0.7804". I guess the "1.0" part is kind of fixed. Good to know.

Comment: I think you cannot do this through the jdbc like you want.